# Succesive transformations to a texture in GLSL

Tags: image, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm trying to do image processing using shaders in GLSL for good performances and portability.

But I have multiple steps to transform the image and each step need the information of the previous step.

For example, I want to blur the image so I need the informations of the pixels surrounding each one to average them, that is not a problem, I just use `texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);` and after the processing I have a `vec4 blurred`

Then, after the blur, I want to do an edge detection on the image previously blurred, but I can't do it using `vec4 blurred` because it does not give me access to the surrounding pixels. And if I use `texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);` again, I do the process on the first image and not on the blurred image.

In other worlds, after each step of image processing I want to have access to all the pixels of the previous step.

(I am using java with libgdx and shaders in GLSL)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach to something like this is to 'ping-pong' between two render-to-texture (RTT) buffers. For example, in the case of a blur followed by an edge detection you might do the following render passes:

1. Render the initial texture into RTT #1 with a shader that does a horizontal gaussian blur.
2. Render RTT #1 into RTT #2 with a shader that does a vertical gaussian blur.
3. Render RTT #2 into RTT #1 with a shader that does the edge detection.

The same principle can be extended to chain together any number of post-processing effects, continuously bouncing between the two buffers.

Note that in my illustration I'm splitting the blur into two passes, taking advantage of the fact that blurs are a separable effect. It's often much more efficient to handle large blur kernels by separating the horizontal and vertical passes, and you end up with the same result.

Comment: OK, thanks for the ping-pong lesson :) ! This seems like a good way to do what I want. I will post my code when I will be done with it (if it works).